# Migration to Win7, VS2013 and 64bit - correct order

Tags: visual-studio-2013, migration, 64-bit, windows-7-x64

We've a solution (~200 projects + tests) which is running on Windows XP SP3, compiles in VS2010 32bit configuration.

The plan is to migrate to Win7, VS2013 and compile under 64-bit.
I know that there is a new MS Windows SDK available for Win7 and VS2013 must make use of it.

What is the most correct order of doing all this stuff - correct in a sense that it will cause minimum hassles, minimum number of repetative operations etc.
Maybe some useful tips..
Thanks

Comment: C#, C++, VB, piece of Fortran

Answer (score 1):

I would migrate to Visual Studio 2013 first, run a full suite of regression tests, and then port to x64.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand it right:
VS2013 under WinXP will use different MS SDK then
VS2013 under Win7, right?

Comment: To support Windows XP in Visual Studio 2013 you set the Platform Toolset to "Visual Studio 2013 - Windows XP (v120_xp)." Setting the Platform Toolset to "Visual Studio 2013 - Windows XP (v120_xp)" does in fact cause Visual Studio to use the v7.1A Windows SDK instead of the Windows Kit 8.1. That is, it will include header files from "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\include" instead of header files from "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include."